# download twitter image with php

Tags: php, twitter

Dear I'm trying to download images associated to tweets but I have a lot of problem.

Firstly I found that `entities->media[0]->media_url` contains the image Url but it is not the same in every tweet.

Now I see a tweet with associated urls for photo on YFROG.com be in `entities->urls`

I can't find the right documentation or example code: can you please help me?
thanks
A

Comment: Some sample xml, test code please...text alone isn't of much help.

Comment: I don't have errors in code: i need to know the method to use to solve the problem. It's why I didn't write code in the question.

Comment: thanks robert. And sorry to all.
My problem is that I found Twitter photo sharing use a lot of different provider and saves a parameter of the image link in an array media->urls . The URLS there are not related to the image itself but are related to the page containing the image and other stuff. Do you have some example on how download the pure image?
thanks

Comment: Andrea, unfortunately for now you will have to use each provider's API (YFrog, etc) to get the actual image from the URL that Twitter gives you. Twitter is working on allowing publishers to use meta tags to specify what the actual image URL is: http://blog.twitter.com/2012/06/experience-more-with-expanded-tweets.html

Comment: Thanks @andrewtweber . Now I'll look to some provider of aggregated API.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the media entities as explained in this doc https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

to get the image , u can use file_get_contents($image)

so ur code would something look like

```
<?php
   $value = file_get_contents($image);
   $fp = fopen('path_to_filename.png', 'w');
   fwrite($fp, $value); 
   fclose($fp); 

?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. For media entities i'm ok. The problem is that, for example, yfrog.com images aren't in entities->media but are in entities-->urls and need to be converted using the api of specific provider...

Comment: oh i have heard @janole tell us about this bug where the some media entities goes missing. I guess the best bet for you would be to parse all the possible place, yes this is a overhead . I am not aware if its a bug....

Comment: unfortunately urls do not contains the reference to the img: they contains link to other pages. I need a method to decode them and grab the img